# AAPT: error: attribute argType (aka com.example.aplikasiforensik:argType) not found

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

**i'm trying to build my app**

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ChatForm">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <argument
            android:name="numQuestions"
            app:argType="integer"/>

        <argument
            android:name="numCorrect"
            app:argType="integer"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

**But the problem is I am getting an error during compile as below:**

C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\AplikasiForensik\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_chat_form.xml:29: AAPT: error: attribute argType (aka com.example.aplikasiforensik:argType) not found.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you need to add dependencies for safe Args, I had the same problem when compiling, but after adding the dependencies it just compiles fine, but the linter of the android studio not recognise "app:argtype" as valid.

```
//In top level gradle

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.3.1"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}

//In app level gradle

apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

then resync the gradle files and run your app, hope it works for you to!

[safe Args page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation)

Comment: I had safe arg working. after some package refactoring it gives such error!